# Ubuntu won't install on hp

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, amd-graphics, amd-processor

I have never experienced any difficulty in installing Ubuntu on Intel system before, so actually this is my first time having stuck on installation for installing Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 on my brand new laptop [hp laptop](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-ba000-notebook-pc-series/10862317/document/c05301860).

It always stuck while trying to load the installation setup. I wonder does it support my laptop or its just simply can't. I am currently at lost in what to do

this is my grub config

```
set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed cdrom-detect/try-usb=true noprompt floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 ignore_uuid boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
```

Comment: Please give more information like, what error is given, etc...

Comment: When `grub` menu appears press e and remove the words `quiet splash` from the `kernel` line. You can then know what is going wrong

Comment: @Arun cant open /dev/sr0: no medium found error kept showing.

Comment: Try using a pendrive. You dont need to format you can just copy all the contents of the disk to the pendrive and use it to boot

Comment: @Arun if pendrive is burning the iso to usb from (https://www.pendrivelinux.com/), it still fails on /dev/sr0: no medium found and ended up with fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed AMD-Vi: event logged IOTLB_INV_TIMEOUT